# How can I fix the blocksy search bar issue with ct_post_type variable?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-theming

When I use the search function to try and search for an article I get no results.
The http query appended to the url is: ?s=article&ct_post_type=post%3Apage%3Aproduct
However when the query is changed to ?s=article&ct_post_type=post%3Apage it is populating the page correctly.

I think it's due to the file inc/components/search.php but so far I've had no luck in fixing this.

I thought maybe it was because I had set all the products to hidden in woocommerce but thats not it either.

Would greatly appreciate any help.